# How to get MIME type of file?

Tags: java, mime-types

I am trying to get MIME type of files in java. Using below code I am getting MIME Type:
`application/octet-stream`

Code:

```
MimetypesFileTypeMap mimeTypesMap = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
String mimeType = mimeTypesMap.getContentType(filePath);
```

for PDF but I am expecting `application/PDF`.

Is there any way to get exact MIME type of file?

Comment: You could map the file extension to a list of mimetypes. Is there a great variety of files that you need the mimetype for?

Comment: Take a look at the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/activation/MimetypesFileTypeMap.html , for the location of the config files. Yours might not have a mapping for .pdf extensions.

Comment: And what is your `filePath`? Content type detection in Java is based on file extensions. If you need something more clever you should check Apache Tika (http://tika.apache.org/1.4/detection.html) or similar projects (e.g. http://256.com/sources/simplemagic/).

Comment: filePath is nothing but complete path of file like "c:/New Folder/test.txt".

Comment: Files do not generally have a mime type stored with them.  You need to infer the type from the file extension, the content of the file, or from some external information you have about the file.

Comment: Another mime type project is simplemagic: http://256stuff.com/sources/simplemagic/

Answer (score 4):

This works for me

```
String url = file.getAbsolutePath();
FileNameMap fileNameMap = URLConnection.getFileNameMap();
String mime = fileNameMap.getContentTypeFor("file://"+url);
```