# How to use FileNameMap interface in Java?

Tags: java, interface

This interface provides one method, namely getContentTypeFor(String fileName). However, I have no idea how to use it. I implemented interface in Eclipse and ended with:

```
import java.net.FileNameMap;

public class Fnam implements FileNameMap {

public static void main(String[] args) {

}

@Override
public String getContentTypeFor(String fileName) {
    return null;
}
}
```

The method returns null. How should I change it to get the MIME type ?

Comment: How is it a duplicate ? My question refers to usage of FileNameMap interface, not getting a Mime type of a file in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is interface for inner implementation of JDK, and in most cases you should use just interface implementation, not interface itself.

Here simple sample of usage:

```
public class Main {
    private static FileNameMap fileNameMap = URLConnection.getFileNameMap();

    public static void main(String... str) {
        System.out.print(fileNameMap.getContentTypeFor("my_file.xml"));
    }

}
```

prints:

```
application/xml
```

And [seems](http://srcrr.com/java/oracle/openjdk/6/reference/java/net/FileNameMap.html) only `MimeTable` is only current implementation of that interface in JDK.

Answer (score 0):

A FileNameMap is an interface returned by methods of a class that understands filetypes. For example there is a URLConnection class that has a getFileNameMap() method, which is used like this.

```
private void requestIntent(Uri uri) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    FileNameMap mime = URLConnection.getFileNameMap();
    String mimeType = mime.getContentTypeFor(uri.getPath());
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
    try {
        mActivity.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, OResource.string(mActivity, R.string.toast_no_activity_found_to_handle_file), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

That example from [here](http://programtalk.com/java-api-usage-examples/java.net.FileNameMap/)

So, you usually do not use FileNameMap in isolation. Instead you either use an existing library class that creates objects that implement FileNameMap. If you did want to implement such a library you would need to write code like this (taken from the source of UrlConnection)

```
public static synchronized FileNameMap More getFileNameMap() {
316         if ((fileNameMap == null) && !fileNameMapLoaded) {
317             fileNameMap = sun.net.www.MimeTable.loadTable();
318             fileNameMapLoaded = true;
319         }
320 
321         return new FileNameMap() {
322             private FileNameMap map = fileNameMap;
323             public String getContentTypeFor(String fileName) {
324                 return map.getContentTypeFor(fileName);
325             }
326         };
327     }
```

You see here that the implementation creates an anonymous class implementing the interface; your responsibility as implementor of the interface would be to figure a way to implement that getContentTypeFor() method.

If all you want to do is get the mime type for a file then you can use URLConnection to give you an object that already has that implementation, and so just use the approach shown in the answer to the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25142342/how-to-get-mime-type-of-file)

Comment: The first example refers to Android and not plain Java, the second has some problems when I tried to run it