# What URL.setFileNameMap(FileNameMap map) is used for?

Tags: java, url

What `URL.setFileNameMap(FileNameMap map)` method does, how to use it correctly and what is it used for? Is it any useful at all?

[Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setFileNameMap-java.net.FileNameMap-) are not very much of an explanation:

> **public static void setFileNameMap(FileNameMap map)**
>
> Sets the FileNameMap

+

> **public static FileNameMap getFileNameMap()**
>
> Loads filename map (a *mimetable*) from a data file. It will first try
>   to load the user-specific table, defined by "content.types.user.table"
>   property. If that fails, it tries to load the default built-in table.

**What is a mimetable and FileMap?**

P.S. I read the docs for interface [*FileNameMap*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/FileNameMap.html). It is also very brief and gives me no clue:

> A simple interface which provides a mechanism to *map between a file
>   name and a MIME type string*.
>
> *String getContentTypeFor(String fileName)*
>
> Gets the MIME type for the specified file name. *Returns: a String
>   indicating the MIME type for the specified file name*.

P.S. There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41423633/how-to-use-filenamemap-interface-in-java)  about FileNameMap here, but it was not accepted and does not answer my question.

Comment: Your title seems to be wrong. You mean `URLConnection.setFileNameMap`,
not `URL.setFileNameMap`

Answer (score 0):

This `FileNameMap` is internally used by method [`URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromName-java.lang.String-).
It is implemented like this:

```
public static String guessContentTypeFromName(String fname) {
    return getFileNameMap().getContentTypeFor(fname);
}
```